# Rebbe Nachman and learning Mussar

Tags: mussar-ethics, breslov

At the end of the Noam Elimelech, R' Elimelech has *"Hanhagos Ha'adam"*. In it, he writes that one should spend spend time every day learning *sifrei mussar*:

> ד. ויעסוק באימה וביראה באיזה ספרי מוסר בכל יום, בראשית חכמה ושל״ה וחובות הלבבות:

Did Rebbe Nachman encourage a daily study of *sifrei mussar* as well?

Comment: Is the second half of the question related/predicated  somehow on the first?

Comment: @Oliver both are chasidic rabbis, so the OP asked if this guideline is admitted by other chasidic leaders, e.g. Rabbi Nachman